# Unique constraint in Postgres based on last non-null value

Tags: sql, postgresql, database-design, concurrency, constraints

I have a table that looks like the following: `create table prices_history (id0 serial primary key, product_id0 int, time_added timestamptz, listed_price numeric)`

I would like to only insert a new `price` for a particular `product_id0` into the table when `max(time_added)` of that `product_id0` is distinct from the price I'm about to insert. Currently, I'm doing this through the following query, assuming that I want to insert a price of `9.50` for the product with id `101`:

```
  insert into prices_history (product_id0, time_added, price) 
  (
    select 101, NOW(), 9.50 where not exists (
      select * from (
        select distinct on (product_id0) * from prices_history order by product_id0, time_added desc
      ) x where product_id0=101 and listed_price=9.50
    )
  ) returning id0
```

Is there a better query to solve this problem?

I'm using Postgres `v9.6.8` on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.

Comment: to 2): An index is not a filter. It would be better to formulate a query that will give you the current prices, and create a (materialized) view for this query, if necessary. After that you should analyze your query with `EXPLAIN` and optimize its performance with appropriate indexes.

Comment: If you are trying to avoid creating a duplicate productid/price/date then why not just create a unique constraint on that? Also, why the nested query in the exists clause? Its doing nothing for you. But I don't think there is a window in any case.  Someone else can probably answer that for sure.

Comment: @clemens what would the benefit be of making the materialized view for this query? How could I use that in the current context?

Comment: A materialized view is a view which stores it's content permanently, and you may create indexes on it. If you use them correctly, you can speed up complicated queries enormously. However, they are often only useful for tables that are rarely changed.

Comment: @clemens I expect to be inserting into this table very often.

Comment: A materialized view is just only one option.

Comment: I would create an ordinary view which displays the relevant rows, analyze the queries on that view with `EXPLAIN`, and create appropriate indices to get better performances.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using `WHERE NOT EXISTS`, I found that a more sustainable solution to do bulk inserts was `LEFT JOIN..WHERE NULL`. This involves doing a left join with the data I wanted to insert, choosing the data where there was no matching data in the old table. In the following example, say I had the following pricing data (represented as JSON):

```
[{price: 11.99, product_id0:2},
 {price: 10.50, product_id0:3},
 {price: 10.00, product_id0:4}]
```

The following query, would insert a subset of this data if any of it is new information:

```
insert into prices_history (product_id0, time_added, price)
(
   select new_product_id0, new_time_added, new_price from
     (select unnest(array[11.99, 10.50, 10.00]) as new_price, unnest(array[2,3,4]) as new_product_id0, now() as new_time_added) new_prices left join
     (select distinct on (product_id0) * from prices_history order by product_id0, time_added desc) old_prices 
   on old_prices.product_id0 = new_prices.new_product_id0 and old_prices.listed_price= new_prices.new_price 
   where old_prices.product_id0 is null and old_prices.listed_price is null
) returning id0
```

This new query seems to work well in the current deployment.